# Calling a WCF service from a client without having the contract interface and DTO

Tags: wcf, wsdl, metadata, servicecontract

I have 3rd party wcf soap service which needs to-be consume so i have [discovered](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328552/Calling-a-WCF-service-from-a-client-without-having?msg=4437111#xx4437111xx) a way to generate code in memory and invoke the service with simple input arguments. I would like to do the same with complex arguments can anyone please help me as to how i can achieve this. Or can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance,
Pavan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use output of datasvcutil at runtime with dynamic code generation/reflection.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756369.aspx

Comment: This is similar to svcutil.exe; we can produce C# files using datasvcutil.exe or svcutil.exe. Is there a way to produce in memory, refence them in memory and hit the service with in memory objects.